# iOS: Draw diagram

Tags: ios, charts

I need a little bar diagram in my app. What do you think. Can this be implemented easily by myself or should I use library for this? They y-axis is dynamic, Values go from 0 to 1000.
Not so sure how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: Not very difficult to do but it will probably be quickest with a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- add a view with fix height call that one base view. 
2- add a subview to base view call innerView. 
3- make outlet of height constraint of innerView.
4- update height Constraint according to the ratio of that particular day.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var innerBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var heightOfInnerView: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setTheHeightOFbrar(score: 790, totalScore: 1000)
}
func setTheHeightOFbrar(score:Double,totalScore:Double){
    let heightofBar = CGFloat(score/totalScore)
    let innerBarHeight = 400 * heightofBar

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0) {
        self.heightOfInnerView.constant = CGFloat(innerBarHeight)
        self.innerBar.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

}

[image]